Defining rank of an abelian subgroup using the second centralizer
I recently posted this on MSE, but didn't receive any feedback; so I'm posting it on MO.
I recently came across this article which explored the maximal abelian subgroups of the symmetric group $S_n$. The author defines an "abelian rank" of a maximal abelian subgroup of $S_n$ thusly:

Let $M$ be a maximal abelian subgroup of a non-abelian group $G$. We define the "abelian rank of $M$ as the minimal cardinality of a set $A \subseteq M$ such that $\cup_{a \in A} C^2(a) = M$. The "second centralizer" of $a$, $C^2(a)$ is defined $C^2(a) = \{x \in G : xb = bx \text{ for every } b \in C(a)\}$.

It seems like the abelian rank, as the author defines it, is related to the definition of rank for a non-abelian group (size of the smallest generating set), but it's distinct from that notion. As a matter of fact, the author gives an example of a group of an abelian subgroup of $S_6$ which has abelian rank 2, but is generated by three elements.
$$C^2((12)(34))C^2((12)(56)) \simeq \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$$
As far as I can tell, the use of the second centralizers to define algebraic structures comes from their utilization in finding abelian sub-semigroups. Is this notion of using the second centralizer to define a 'rank' a novel notion for group theory, or has it been studied previously?
